# Jquery empty field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

when i submit the form with empty fields i get the success message in the dialog box. Instead i want to show error message in the dialog box. Please help me to find the solution.

My html code:

```
<form id="booking" action="" method="post">
  First Name:<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" maxlength="30" /><br/>
  Last Name:<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" maxlength="30"/><br/>
  Contact:<input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" maxlength="15"/><br/>
  Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30"/><br/>
  <input id="save" type="button" value="Save" />
  </form>
  <div id="dialog"></div>
```

Jquery code:

```
 $('#save').click(function(){
    if(('#firstName').length==0 && ('#lastName').length==0 && ('#contact').length==0 &&   ('#email').length==0){
     $('#dialog').attr('title','Error').text('All fields are required').dialog();
     }else{
     $('#dialog').attr('title','Success').text('Success').dialog();
     }
    });
```

Comment: I would look into `jquery-validate` plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('#firstName')` -> if you are using jQuery this should be `$('#firstName')`

this conditions will always return false : 
`('#firstName').length==0 && ('#lastName').length==0 && ('#contact').length==0 &&   ('#email').length==0`

to get the value length of a input type text:

```
$('#firstName).val().length
```

**update:**

try this:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    if($('#firstName').val().length==0 && $('#lastName').val().length==0 && $('#contact').val().length==0 &&   $('#email').val().length==0){
     $('#dialog').text('All fields are required').dialog({title:'Error'});
    } else{
     $('#dialog').text('Success').dialog({title:'Success'});
    }
 });
```

Comment: it's alright, but title is still the same 'Error' i want to change it to 'Success'

Comment: Your code is perfect.. i see the title 'Success'. The logic is awesome. 'val().length==0'

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    if($('#firstName').val()=="" || $('#lastName').val()=="" || $('#contact').val()=="" ||   $('#email').val()==""){
     $('#dialog').attr('title','Error').text('All fields are required').dialog();
     }else{
     $('#dialog').attr('title','Success').text('Success').dialog();
     }
    });
```

Comment: you missed $ infront of the selector. Edited the answer. Now try

Comment: oh wait.. i got the success message, but the title is still ERROR. How come?

Comment: @user1897595 its ok. Just accept the answer if it really helps you

Comment: I did, but i don't have 15 reputation. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

it should be OR in your if condition `||` and you can use `[val()][1]` to get the value of selected element and check if it is empty.

**and you missed `$` in your jquery selector**

```
if(('#firstName').val()==""
---^--- //here missing $
```

try this

```
$('#save').click(function(){
  if($('#firstName').val()=='' || $('#lastName').val()=='' || $('#contact').val()=='' ||  $('#email').val==''){
     $('#dialog').attr('title','Error').text('All fields are required').dialog();
  }else{
    $('#dialog').attr('title','Success').text('Success').dialog();
  }
});
```

Comment: oh wait.. i got the success message, but the title is still ERROR. How come?